# Is $ f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know that the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$, but according to the definition of differentiable functions:

> A differentiable function of one real variable is a function whose derivative exists at each point in its domain

since $x = 0$ is not in the domain of $f$, it doesn't have to be differentiable at that point for the function to be differentiable. This suggests that $f$ is differentiable as every other points in the domain has a derivative of $0$.

However, some say that a function must be continuous if it's differentiable. This disproves the fact that $f$ is differentiable since it's not a continuous function.

Then is it really a differentiable function?

Comment: This is a good time to be clear of what type $f$ really is. You write "the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$". What most people would infer is that it is $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) := \frac{x}{x}$. Then $f$ is cts. on its whole domain. I would even go so far to say that the statement "f is discontinuous at 0" and "f is continous at 0" are both ill-formed. You can only talk about continuity on points in the domain.

Comment: @ComFreek "I would even go so far to say that the statement "f is discontinuous at 0" and "f is continous at 0" are both ill-formed."... I would hardly call that "far" at all.  I'd say that is a basic fact.

Answer (score 6):

$\frac xx$ is continuous at all points in its domain.  It has derivative $0$ at all points of $\Bbb R$ except $0$.

Comment: So do you mean the function itself is differentiable?

Comment: Yes, it is......

Comment: Can't he write that $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}=1$ ?

Comment: When $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @FareedAF:  the point is that $\frac xx$ is not defined for $x=0$.  If you restrict the domain of $f(x)$ to $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ then that is correct.  If you just say $\frac xx=1$ you imply that the domain on the right is all of $\Bbb R$, which is not correct.

Comment: He cant write that $f(x) = 1$ because that implies $f(0) = 1$.  And $0$ is not in the domain.  But he *could* write.  $f:\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb R$ via $f(x)=1$.  That would be the same function.  Specifying the domain is a necessary determination of a function.  It doesn't always need to be explicitly expressed; it can be implicitly expressed.  But it must be expressed.

Answer (score 6):

> "I know that the function $f(x)=\frac xx$ is not differentiable at $x=0$"

The function isn't *ANYTHING* at $x=0$.  $0$ is not in the domain.

> since x=0 is not in the domain of f, it doesn't have to be differentiable at that point for the function to be differentiable. This suggests that f is differentiable as every other points in the domain has a derivative of 0.

Absolutely correct.

> However, some say that a function must be continuous if it's differentiable. This disproves the fact that f is differentiable since it's not a continuous function.

But $f$ *is* a continuous function.  It's continuous at every point of its domain.... which doesn't include $0$.

Answer (score 3):

The function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ has a natural domain of $\Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$; you can sensibly substitute in any value except $0$. In order to be continuous or differentiable at a point, it is **required** that the point be part of the domain of the function. The function $f$ is therefore **neither continuous nor differentiable at $0$**.

Does this mean the function is continuous? It depends on who's asking. Some people define the term "continuous" as being defined and continuous at every point on $\Bbb{R}$, and say that all points where the function is undefined are points of discontinuity by default. Others say that a function is "continuous" if it is continuous at every point on its domain. In the latter sense, $f$ is continuous and differentiable. In the former sense, $f$ is neither.

Comment: As [commented above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3306571/is-fracxx-differentiable?noredirect=1#comment6803094_3306571), I find saying "$f$ is [...] neither continuous nor [...]" potentially a bit misleading to beginners. Namely, reading it like $\lnot \left(\text{continuous}\ f\ 0\right)$ might imply that there somehow is a violated continuity property — which there isn't. (For me, it's simply a type error to call the $\text{continuous}$ predicate on $0$ outside the domain.)

Comment: @ComFreek That's fair, though I feel I should point out that I have seen plenty of high school and first year university instructors who have talked about continuity in this manner. It might be better to say that $f$ cannot possibly be continuous or differentiable at points where it is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

To see why the function $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ is differentiable everywhere except at $0$, and has derivative equal to $0$ where it is differentiable, consider the following:

The graph of $f(x) = \frac{x}{x}$ is the graph of $y=1$ with the point $(0,1)$ removed. Hence, $f'(x) = 0$ over $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$  and $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.